# How to delete items in Drag and Drop Angular Cdk 8.0.0

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material-6, angular-cdk

I usign drag and drop in proyect using angular 6 and angular-cdk 8.0.0, i need to move the elements for know where is the order, update and aslo delete them but i dont know how can do that

I tryed to use the api in angular cdk but im got more confuse and me tried to delete the item from array but the drag an drop has been corrupted

```html
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let name of names" cdkDrag>
        {{name}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
  names: string[];
  order: number[];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.order, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    moveItemInArray(this.names, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
onYesClick(): void {
   for(let i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++){
   this.dashboard.updateChartOrder(this.charts[i],this.order[i]).subscribe();

   }
    this.dialogRef.close({});
  }
```

The error has been had es the item never dessapear when i delete the item from array